# How to use Spring's reactive WebClient in a Spring Web Application which runs on Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

Unable to use Spring's reactive WebClient in a Spring boot based Web Application which runs on Tomcat. Application startup itself is failing due to unresolved dependencies.

I looked at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9690 but unfortunately thats not an option for me as I cannot set the WebApplication type to None

My gradle file:

```java
dependencies {

    compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa') {
        exclude(module: 'tomcat-juli')
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-redis'


    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.session', name: 'spring-session'

    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-java8'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '5.2.4.Final'

    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-guava'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-hibernate5'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310'

    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.3.2'
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql'

    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version:'0.9.0'

    compile group: 'com.nimbusds', name: 'nimbus-jose-jwt', version:'5.12'

    // Spring managed dependency is not working, so resorted to using specific version
    // compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux', version: '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    /*
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web-reactive', version: '5.0.0.M1'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.1.6.RELEASE'
    */


    implementation 'com.auth0:jwks-rsa:0.7.0

}

bootRepackage {
    enabled = false
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/client/reactive/ClientHttpConnector
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient.create(WebClient.java:144)
```

I then tried adding,

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web-reactive', version: '5.0.0.M1'
```

Which then complained about something else, which made me add

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.1.6.RELEASE'
```

But then another error shows up while starting my application, which makes me think there is some other problem.

To be precise,I simply want to call a MicroService using Reactive WebClient from within another MicroService (which is Spring Boot based Web Application).

**Using RestTemplate works fine** but I just wanted to try the reactive WebClient and stuck with error.

Due to the way we host our dependencies, managed dependencies are not working. Our dependency server is unable to resolve them. That's the reason for having specific version of spring boot dependencies

Answer (score 1):

`org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpConnector` is part of the `spring-web` jar so it should be available if use use `spring-boot-starter-webflux` or `spring-boot-starter-web`. If you're writing a traditional servlet based application then you should be using `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Check the output of `gradle dependencies` to ensure that you have a `spring-web` jar. If you do, the chances are it's somehow been corrupted and you should clear your gradle cache.

I'd also recommend that you use Spring Boot's [managed dependencies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies) rather than specifify version numbers on each dependency. This will ensure that you get versions that are known to work well together.

Comment: Yes mine is traditional Servlet based app (Restful web service). W.r.to your suggestion on using `spring-boot-starter-web`, it doesn't have have reactive `WebClient` which am trying to use to invoke another microservice (graphql endpoint) from my application

Comment: btw `spring-boot-starter-webflux` is not downloading the reactive classes needed mentioned in the [Spring tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/)

Comment: Please update your question with a more comprehensive build file. It's hard to help you since your question is suggesting several incompatible attempts. The spring guide you're pointing at is working, it's tested by a CI env.

Comment: @BrianClozel updated my question and also uploaded my dependencies here: [gradle-dependencies.json](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=72713440509422344360). The dependencies do list spring-web but I wonder why I still get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/client/reactive/ClientHttpConnector`